# R, gsub does not work when try to get subset of hyperlink

Tags: r, gsub

I tried to run code like below. I wonder why the gsub function did not worked on this input. Anyone know why and how to handle this case?

```
> text

[1] <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ubersocial-for-twitter/id396050119 mt=8&uo=4" rel="nofollow">UberSocial for Twitter on iOS</a>
65 Levels: <a href="http://aktualpost.com" rel="nofollow">Aktualpost</a> ...
> start = as.numeric(regexpr(">",text)[[1]])+1
> start
[1] 103
> to_cut = substr(text,1,start-1)
> to_cut
[1] "<a href=\"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ubersocial-for-twitter/id396050119?mt=8&uo=4\" rel=\"nofollow\">"
> new_text = gsub(to_cut,"",as.character(text))
> new_text
[1] "<a href=\"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ubersocial-for-twitter/id396050119?mt=8&uo=4\" rel=\"nofollow\">UberSocial for Twitter on iOS</a>"
```

Comment: `text` is a factor. First convert it to character: `as.character(text)`

Comment: It is because there is `?` that is not matching with the `text`

Comment: This is not a good title for a question.

Comment: If you're looking to remove the anchor tags from the text, a perhaps easier method would be to just use `gsub('(?U)<.*>', '', as.character(text), perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `?` in "to_cut" that is not found in "text".  If we fix that, it should work, i.e. check `?mt` in "to_cut" and `mt` in "text".

```
gsub("^<a href=\"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ubersocial-for-twitter/id396050119 mt=8&uo=4\" rel=\"nofollow\">(.*)", "\\1", text)
#[1] "UberSocial for Twitter on iOS</a>"
```

It is not clear how the OP got the "to_cut" with the `?`

```
start = as.numeric(regexpr(">",text)[[1]])+1
to_cut <-substr(text,1,start-1)
to_cut
#[1] "<a href=\"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ubersocial-for-twitter/id396050119 mt=8&uo=4\" rel=\"nofollow\">"
gsub(to_cut, "", text)
#[1] "UberSocial for Twitter on iOS</a>"
```